# App crashes when setting constraint programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am creating a toast view pragmatically(using some help from SO) and setting a vertical constraint on it. When I try to use a dynamic value within the constraint, the app crashes with below message:

```
Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a ')' at the end of a constraint modifier, or a ',' before another constraint modifier 
V:|-(>=66.0-[toastView(==40)]-68-| 
           ^
```

***Code for toast:***

```
func showToastWithMessage(_ message : String, _ bottomBarHeight: CGFloat?) {
        guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else {
            return
        }
        if let toast = window.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UILabel && $0.tag == -1001 }) {
            toast.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        let toastView = UILabel()
        toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        toastView.textColor = UIColor.white
        toastView.textAlignment = .center
        toastView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .medium)
        toastView.text = message
        toastView.numberOfLines = 0
        toastView.alpha = 0
        toastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        toastView.tag = -1001
        
        window.addSubview(toastView)
        
        let horizontalCenterContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: window, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        
        let widthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: (self.frame.size.width-25) )
        
        var bannerPlacement = 300.0
        
        if let height = bottomBarHeight {
            bannerPlacement = height + 10.0
        }
        
        let verticalContraint: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(>=\(bannerPlacement)-[toastView(==40)]-68-|", options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["toastView": toastView])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalCenterContraint, widthContraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalContraint)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            toastView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                toastView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                toastView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        })
    }
```

App crashes on "V:|-(>=(bannerPlacement)-[toastView(==40)]-68-|" due to (bannerPlacement) while creating verticalConstraint object. If I put a static value over there, everything works fine, but in my case the value is dynamic. How do I add a variable in it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've taken the liberty for properly format the error message, which reveals additional information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what exactly you want to achieve and express with the visual format expression, so I can only focus on the formal syntax problem.

Obviously, the parentheses are not balanced. That is what the iOS is complaining about.

Most likely, you are missing a closing parenthesis after `66.0`:

Instead of:

```
V:|-(>=66.0-[toastView(==40)]-68-|
```

the expression should look like this:

```
V:|-(>=66.0)-[toastView(==40)]-68-|
```